# Creating a named FIFO using systemd-tmpfiles as non-root user

Tags: linux, systemd, mkfifo

I want to create a named FIFO using systemd-tmpfiles as specified in the manual at [tmpfiles.d | p,p+](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html#p). I am able to create the fifo but the issue is with the user and group of that named fifo. Here is how I am defining it in conf file:

```
p+ /run/reboot 0644 system system - -
```

But the fifo is always created as `root.root` even if I specify it as system system in the conf file.

If I run the systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service script after bootup, then it the fifo is with system.system privileges.

```
/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove --boot --exclude-prefix=/dev
```

So, either systemd-tmpfiles is creating it as `root.root` at bootup or some other service is changing permissions (not systemd-udev-trigger - tried masking this but no change).

For debug purpose, I ran this script (`lsing`) as `ExecStartPort` of `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` which does `ls -la` on `/run` and writes to `/run/lsing.txt`. Even there, I see the fifo is `root.root`,

```
ExecStartPost=/sbin/lsing
```

Need some help in debugging this issue. I am quite new to systemd.

Comment: In the absence of a knowledgeable answerer, I'll try to help... What distro of linux is this?  Is it possible that the user system and user root are both uid 0, or that user system doesn't exist?

Comment: There's also some references to `chown` by systemd-tmpfiles failing when /proc isn't mounted... so maybe that's something else to verify